# Let's get MathOverflow's “Citation Helper” here, as well!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, citations

MathOverflow and [Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22008/lets-get-mathoverflows-citation-helper-here-too) have a [citation helper](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2583/new-feature-citation-helper) that adds a new button to the post editor to allow references to journal articles (and conference papers?) to be added to posts quicker and easier.

[image]

Of course we need this, too.  Who agrees with me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update:

Thank you everyone for your input and feedback. **The citation helper has been added to this site.**

Enjoy!

---

*<original post>*

I suspect citation support would be a good fit here, but I don't have an *objective* overview of your content or a sense if anybody would actually *use* this to make that case. The best way I know to make this happen is is to demonstrate a *need* for citations in actual practice. I'm basing that off how we decide if a site needs features like LaTeX support (for example).

**I would suggest compiling a collection of posts below which would be markedly improved with citation support.** If the benefit to this site can be demonstrated substantively, I can send it off to the folks who can make that happen.

Good luck!

Comment: @Bjørn On an administrative note (talking over your shoulder to the rest of the community), right now you're one user asking AND doing all the work to show this is needed, so I don't really have any insight if others want/need this feature. I don't know how to fix this "ask", but posting your list as an answer might spur others into doing the same for more signal and feedback. Pragmatically speaking, I can probably get this enabled this time, but I'm trying to figure how to make similar requests functionally more effective without assuming everything said here is both correct and useful.

Comment: OK thanks, I've posted my list as an answer. I see what you're saying about not just saying Yes to everything...

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Nice job! I was able to get the citation helper added to this site.

Comment: A thousand thanks

Answer (score 2):

Some posts where this would be helpful:

First some of my own answers; in some cases I used the citation helper on MathOverflow and pasted it into CSTheory, but that's a bit inconvenient.

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/41555/1993

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/41479/1993

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/41425/1993

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/40111/1993

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/39947/1993

Next, the highest voted questions on CSTheory are often asking for references or sources for results:

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/1550/1993

[What papers should everyone read?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1168/1993)

[What Books Should Everyone Read?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3253/1993)

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/18866/1993